# What this.innerHTML means here?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on Angela Yu's course on udemy, Drum Kit project
In that JS file she uses `var drum_note = this.innerHTML;` inside of the anonymous function that's passed to `addEventListener()` as a listener.

I needed to know how that `this` works in this case, I knew the concepts like its used to point an Object, but how exactly it points towards the button.

**My index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>

  <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/1CsEvbpeEVcek0pxt8SIv4" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  <footer>
    Made with ❤️ in London.
  </footer>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**My Index.js**

```
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var drum_note = this.innerHTML;
    switch (drum_note) {
      case "w":
        var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
        tom1.play();
        break;
      case "a":
        var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
        tom2.play();
        break;
      case "s":
        var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
        tom3.play();
        break;
      case "d":
        var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
        tom4.play();
        break;
      case "j":
        var kick_Bass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
        kick_Bass.play();
        break;
      case "k":
        var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
        crash.play();
        break;
      case "l":
        var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
        snare.play();
        break;
      default:

    }
  })
}
```

Comment: What is it you don't understand? `this` inside an event handler refers to the element the event was raised by.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @Jamiec: It refers to the element the handler is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you shouldn't rely on innerHTML to pass values as it may change in future which would break your code.

Use a [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute, then grab the value on click and use that as the filename, this way you don't have to add 4 lines for every sound.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".drum").forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let note = this.dataset.note
    // new Audio(`sounds/${note}.mp3`).play();
    console.log(`playing: sounds/${note}.mp3`)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <button class="drum" data-note="tom-1">w</button>
  <button class="drum" data-note="tom-2">a</button>
  <button class="drum" data-note="tom-3">s</button>
  <button class="drum" data-note="tom-4">d</button>
  <button class="drum" data-note="kick-bass">j</button>
  <button class="drum" data-note="crash">k</button>
  <button class="drum" data-note="snare">l</button>
</div>
```

You could obviously build it out and have `data-instrument="drum"` and query select on `"[data-instrument]"` then do:

```
new Audio(`sounds/${instrument}/${note}.mp3`).play();
```

Then have hundreds of different instruments without needing to add each of them to the switch.

Answer (score 0):

"this" here refers to the specific button that you are going to click which will then play that specific sound.

Answer (score 0):

this.innerHTML there points what is inside the button. In your case, it represents drum_notes like w,a,s,d,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the JavaScript keyword `this` "refers back" to the object the function "belongs to".  `this` can't be set (or overwritten) by assignment during execution, and the value for `this` will be different each time the function gets called (because it has a different owner).

In this case...

You created a button-event...for each button...in a set of buttons. As such, the value of `this` refers back to the HTML Element (which is a specific button).  The HTML Element has a property called InnerHTML...which in this case...contains the corresponding letter for said button.

The case statement then keys-off the InnerHTML's text value & plays the correct note.

...Cheers!

Comment: *"the value for `this` will be different each time the function gets called"* Not if I all the function "on" the same object.

Comment: I'm not saying that an extensive explanation of `this` is necessary. It just seems to be that this statement is more confusing than it is helping in understanding the nature of `this`. Because, to repeat my example, if I call the same method on the same object then `this` will refer to that same object. It's not suddenly a different object (e.g. a copy) just because I called the function.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside of a function solely depends on how this function is invoked, ie like a regular function, a method, or with `this` otherwise explicitly bound.

In the case you're asking, you're passing a callback function to `addEventListener()`, so `addEventListener()` has control on how to call it. It turns out that it actually binds the callback function local `this` variable to the object it itself is executed as a method on.

The code for `addEventListener()` probably goes something like this:

```
function addEventListener(eventName, callback){
  // Some code
  // Execute the callback, binding its local `this` variable to the addEventListener() own `this` - the Object.prototype.call() method allows to explicitly set the `this` execution context.
  callback.call(this, eventName)
}
```

Again, here, `this` will actually point to the HTML element `addEventListener()` is called as a method on. The callback is then called with its local `this` bound to this same element.

Comment: Thats very helpful! You got me cleared!!!!! Thankkkkkkkkks!!!!